# Angular 2 & Autonumeric.js - problems on .multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-plugins

I receive this error in a component when I'm using this plugin:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'multiple' of undefined
    at PreventiviTableComponent.ngAfterViewInit (advanced-search.component.ts:629)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.es5.js:11189)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.es5.js:11164)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.es5.js:11148)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12253)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12568)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12246)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12610)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12542)

---

I use the plugin this way:
ngAfterViewInit() {

```
            AutoNumeric.multiple(['#filtroImportoMin', '#filtroImportoMax'], {
                digitGroupSeparator: '.',
                decimalCharacter: ',',
                modifyValueOnWheel: 'false',
                decimalPlaces: 0
            })

}
```

And in the same component I have imported autonumeric like this:

import { AutoNumeric } from 'autonumeric';.

If I put an "windows.setTimeout" near my function it seems to work (but now well in really...).

I didn't imported autonumeric in my app.modules because I meet some issues.

I just imported it in my Angular-cli.json this way

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js",
        "../node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js",
        "../node_modules/list.js/dist/list.min.js",
        **"../node_modules/autonumeric/dist/autoNumeric.min.js",**
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
        "main.js"

        ]
```

I'm trying to resolve this issue by 2 days but nothing...This plugin seems to work on some components, not in others...

Comment: Try to move `autoNumeric.min.js` in your scripts to the top. Maybe it's not loaded yet, whe you trying to use it.

Comment: nah, still doesn't work

Comment: Hi, AutoNumeric author here, the error message you get seems pretty clear; you are trying to access the `AutoNumeric` object while it is still not defined. I'm guessing there is a problem with the way you are loading the library.